# How can I pass this to an interface used in a property of this?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to describe a property that holds event listeners. The listeners are called with the object firing the event as first argument. When I try to pass "this" as a Generic argument to the events interface. I get the error: " Argument of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Base'"

```
interface BaseEvents<me extends Base> {
    render: (me:me) => void
}

class Base {
    public listeners?:BaseEvents<this>
}

class Child extends Base {
    foo() {
    }
}

function create<T extends typeof Base>(cls: T) {
    return new cls;
};

const c = create(Child);
```

Full error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Base'.
    Construct signature return types 'Child' and 'Base' are incompatible.
    The types of 'listeners' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'BaseEvents<Child> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'BaseEvents<Base> | undefined'.
        Type 'BaseEvents<Child>' is not assignable to type 'BaseEvents<Base>'.
        Property 'foo' is missing in type 'Base' but required in type 'Child'.ts(2345)
```

Does anybody know how I can avoid this error?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QKIDcLgYA8AtihAB6QgAmGamEAfMgN4CwAUAJBQE3QAXMgAUZQWQCUyALwtcAe2A0uAXy5cEAG0z10WNl24AHAK4AjLcATIrGatAwB+Qfpz5CRMAAtgGJmoanNq6yADCvlo0yJTUdAwGHDwwCgoi0knc6pzZXDCmIAhgwAogyAh8cJBEACoxVPz0YACexhAKMAnMItoYwjUZRnxgplBlIBAA7uVaGADcagucmqX25bLllZAiEcBRkktAA)

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly update `BaseEvents`

```js
interface BaseEvents<Me extends Base> {
    render: <T extends Me>(me: T) => void
}

class Base {
    public listeners?: BaseEvents<this>
}

class Child extends Base {
    foo() { }
}


function create<T extends typeof Base>(cls: T) {
    return new cls();
};

const c = create(Child); // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOG1Rw)

This is because `Me` in `BaseEvents` in in contravariant position. For instance, try to write BaseEvents in this way:

```js
interface BaseEvents<Me extends Base> {
    render: Me
}
```

You will see that there is no more error in `const c = create(Child);`

Comment: Thanks! That works. The only thing I don't like is having to put <T extends Me>  before every listener but I guess I'll have to live with that :)

Answer (score 1):

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEA8qB8yA3gFDLIgQDuyAFAJQBcaJAviSaJLIigEJwAzhACiANwjhBOALIoIAD0ggAJoOQDhhUuSiSV0ZrQC2EZnPrIAvITEB7YCrYcSCADZD1mlDuSYArgBGbsAIyCGCytCCAPzM3uKSYNJgABbAgvjOrh6C6gDC6W4qyIrKahpCPmTIMHZ2DMQ17OwkMP4gCGDAdiDICHpwkHilSvpeVfi07oLMGNh4%20Ja%20emD%20UH2UNDMA3Gx7rr2R-db9g5C0hcDF9DtAA)

```js
interface Type<T> {
  new (): T
}

interface BaseEvents<Me extends Base> {
  render: (me: Me) => void
}


class Base {
  public listeners?: BaseEvents<this>
}

class Child extends Base {
  foo() {
  }
}

function create<T extends Base>(cls: Type<T>) {
  return new cls;
};

const c = create(Child);
```