# Why do I get Typescript error when trying to infer a generic type? (TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite)

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am trying to infer a type of a generic and get this error. I am creating a library with components that have listeners. The listeners are in maps that belong to the component. I've made this simplified test case where the error shows. But only I pass the events in a specific order:

```
type extractStoreType<ListType> = ListType extends TestA<infer StoreType> ? StoreType : never;
type extractRecordType<StoreType> = StoreType extends TestStore<infer RecordType> ? RecordType : never;
class TestStore<RecordType> {
    data: RecordType[] = []
}

interface ObservableEventMap<Type> {

}

class Observable {
    set listeners(listeners: Partial<ObservableEventMap<this>>) {
        // listeners applied here
    }
}

interface EventMapA<Type>  extends ObservableEventMap<Type> {
    event1:<Sender extends Type> (comp:Sender) => void;
}

interface TestA<StoreType> extends Observable{
    set listeners(listeners: Partial<EventMapA<this>>)
}

class TestA<StoreType> extends Observable {
    store?: StoreType
    constructor(readonly tagName: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap = "div") {
        super();
    }

}


interface EventMapB<Type> extends EventMapA<Type> {
    event2:<Sender extends Type> (comp:Sender, store: extractStoreType<Type>, record: extractRecordType<extractStoreType<Type>>) => void;
}


interface TestB<StoreType> extends TestA <StoreType> {
    set listeners(listeners: Partial<EventMapB<this>>)
}

class TestB<StoreType> extends TestA <StoreType> {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    parent:TestB<StoreType>|undefined;
}


interface TestC<StoreType> extends TestA <StoreType> {
    set listeners(listeners: Partial<EventMapB<this>>)
}

class TestC<StoreType> extends TestB <StoreType> {

    constructor() {
        super();

        const b = new TestB();
        b.parent = this;
    }
}



interface TestRecord {
    id:number,
    name: string
}

const b1 = new TestB<TestStore<TestRecord>>();
b1.listeners = {
    event2: (comp, store, record) => {

    }
};

interface TestBConfig<StoreType>  {
    store: StoreType,
    listeners: Partial<EventMapB<TestB<StoreType>>>
}

const createB = <StoreType>(config:TestBConfig<StoreType>) => {
    const b =  new TestB();
    Object.assign(b, config);
    return b;
}

const b2 = createB({
    store: new TestStore<TestRecord>,
    listeners: {
        // If I remove this listener or move this below event2 it works!
        event1: comp => {

        },
        // this listener ets the error: TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
        event2: (comp, store, record) => {

        },

    }

})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBFAeIBOBDAxiAyiA9kqAKpFADwAyAlgM4hHQB8MAvDJTXbAiFAHYAmVGASg0AgiQo8AZlCQxseQsUYB+ebnwcYALhg8oAN1kBuUMTiJUGAEpQ0ePhxILNy5usVauvAUJFYNUkkZOVt7JEc3NTCHLV19IyRTNAAbFCpBYRoXUhiIjkYAb2AYUpg+FBAUXTzI6ABtAF13JuAAX2BgSW4kKXRYAHkAIypZAxQhlKgAUSMeEABZFAgSAphi9s7U9MFh0aRxydhisphRkBgU6m59JCoACiuaXlkqXQAFFCQQChQUkj2YwmU1mvEWyxIIAAFtR6PQAJTrEqnMoAelRl2uLzuMGWECuUD4MChsigyNKHQ6XXmsj6aFgoPmSwg4jWFhuvkBB2BMzm4JWaxOZUMYIAjNpnD5ZOyfJk3Pd7ABbCDaTBSpCIpiMAw4Ch8UxU7q0-p+MTOQJrbz8XYjIFHIWlc6Y563B5PG6vD5fH5-EiM-niaGwhGbYDbDKmkDiHKWxCymBcw5TJGnGiKFS6GPEckwew8GhIACuGDw93wKD4OB4KTAMCqAHMAHIoRVQXQAaygYBwUhgAAkCAsyNMpq35gQUE2W1Bme4AER8CgGOeIh0oqiF6BIe7w0ynKlU6k9OkMvnMgBCqzcVt8-uZrLca5F8wATBK1fxpTe5QwYAqcMqqrqgANGcgS6FwVgBJ4xBXgwoH4OEfAQZY6AgLUTiQWhWbQHBUBwpq2q6vqoZHsa9KRpeOH4TK1qRqIMDmjBv5rk67rYm6WKul63y-P8d7LJeQZUARobhpk-hURa15xnRWRRox1FFJ0px5gWxYaDuKYoo6m6yDue5lFSpwQF8YLaPJUnMfhAA+haflIkiEganRkb0JryQAwkxri-t+9GKdJLE5mxXGvI8YV3DxPr8WegmQjCIkhlS4mRt5Sm0b4lmBdZyk5mpyAaaWq45qmenbruKk6bmVY0DAQzuPoADulEGaVZRDAAdKZ+DzO4wmGRSpFuSeka1NppR6toPCFoqQyyMBOY8NOugFpI9ZibVFxDKKjVQC1lmrP4ORHTQtRwm1O2dexrruE+fJvn+SoQKBab4AhdgOIRSI5pSpgjR5kmeVWjn1j5Si-hNYGKJmQVQItpw3Z6MCfLxvoCRAl6HUpcLtP9BW5uW3Dnu44NrP+0gUPWFlAyDVM5b5+HfWuBMNSwej7a1lWnMMABWdggJ1OxUzw9xDKBeag9zZT4CAhZIDw9UuWGW31S+7hoETUDnvcrHgRzB3HYEp3oZ9ET0AjZRI1FUOnOiMAAJK9g7MD4IqOBGHWiXOh6ch4DA7ue8J9VQCkOAtc+IDqxQFxNXg7ZUAAhO1pSR+KNXKsweXVTAbSWzp9vB9bcAgII0KcEgSB4LoBCYC+ACsAAcACcNfmJINAoPMvw-FWMDUBY9IZEuoe1nwUBQBAuL8DAEA4MPky1sEkgx1AnUp3AD26P+yqvYEH1IczVU6Xnx+550bTwp0QA)

I hope someone can shed some light on this behaviour.

Thanks!

Merijn

Comment: This doesn't look like a [mre].  For example, your `interface ListenersA<T> {  event1: <S extends T> (comp: S) => void; }` type has `event1` be a generic method, but for what reason? Why is it not just `interface ListenersA<T> {event1: (comp: T)=>void}`?  (Any function which accepts a `T` will also accept any `S extends T`).  If I make just that change it clears up your issue. Since you're not asking to clear it up but to explain it, I'd like to see some motivation for why it's written the way it is before diving too far into it, and hopefully see you pare it down to a smaller repro.

Comment: Thank you for commenting so quickly! Using S extends T is something I don’t fully understand to be honest. It breaks if I don’t here’s why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740120/how-can-i-pass-this-to-an-interface-used-in-a-property-of-this

Comment: You should at least be able to [edit] this code to a version which breaks if I make my suggested change, to motivate the complication. But if you don’t know why your code is the way it is, it’s hard to know how to proceed.  I’m not inclined to go deeply into some other SO question to investigate; the relevant info should be here, in the question.

Comment: You’re right, I will change it.

Comment: I was away for a week so I only just had the time to edit the code. Now it breaks with your fix too. If I don't add the Sender extends Type to the event map then sub components are no longer assignable to their parent type.

Comment: [I don't see anything breaking](https://tsplay.dev/WGdzJw).  Not sure how to proceed.  Note that if you disappear for 10 days and then come back, it's quite likely that everything has completely fallen out of my tiny memory, so I'll end up treating it like a brand new question, and may or may not decide to engage with it.  And since it's not a new question I don't know how many others will see it and step in either.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I need a holiday! You copied only a part of my example code. It definitely breaks!

Comment: See? Small brain.  I'll take another look (with the same absence of guarantee that comes from a brand new question, holidays notwithstanding)

Comment: Okay, well, maybe I kind of remember this.  My suggested approach still works; your augmented code had a logic error the compiler couldn't notice because of its inability to inspect higher order generics very well... and the fix is to just properly specify the value.  Looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQrEW).  I'm still not seeing anything that requires the kind of redundant generics in the code.  But if the question is "why does this happen" and not "how can I fix it" I'd probably have to dig into the compiler which I'm not sure I'll have time to do.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time for helping me! My real use case is more complicated and I hope this helps me finding the fix for that too.

Comment: So how should I proceed here? Stack Overflow is meant to be something like a FAQ and not just a personal tech support service. My goal is therefore to either turn this question into something which can have a well-defined authoritative answer posted underneath it, or redirect it as a duplicate of something else, or to remove the question if it's not likely to help other people.  Which of those, if any, sounds reasonable to you?

Comment: I'd like to turn this into something useful too. My example code is still not reproducing my actual problem correctly. I will try to improve it.